# Convenient way to cd into a frequently-used dir?

Tags: shell, filesystems, symlink, cd-command

A dir I `cd` into a lot has a really long path. I'd like to reduce keystrokes.

I have tried this...

```bsh
sudo ln -s /mnt/c/Users/me/ho/hum/bin /mybin
```

It works, but something about it seems wrong.

Is there a better way?

I currently use bash, but a solution that would still work if I switched shells would be nice.

#### System info

Running Unbutu on Windows Subsystem for Linux.

```bsh
$ uname -a
Linux Hostname 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft #253-Microsoft  \
    Mon Dec 31 17:49:00 PST 2018  \
    x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26802/70524  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146788/70524 https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37181/70524

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use an alias. 
Put

```
alias mb='cd /mnt/c/Users/me/ho/hum/bin'
```

into your `~/.bashrc`. 
Then you can just type `mb`, and bash will execute the `cd` command.

Very many shells — I dare say most, if not all — support aliases. 
However, you would need to add it to the initialization file
(e.g., `.cshrc`, `.zshrc`) of every shell you want to use. 
Be aware that the syntax of the `alias` command may vary between shells.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `cd` searches relative to your working directory (if you specify a relative path, rather than an absolute path).  You can add to the directories which will be searched for a match by setting the `CDPATH` environment variable in one of your shell initialization files.  This is supported in at least `bash` and `ksh`.

From the [`bash` manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> **CDPATH**
>
> The search path for the **cd** command. This is a colon-separated list of directories in which the shell looks for destination directories specified by the **cd** command. A sample value is ".:~:/usr".

For your example, if you had set

```
export CDPATH=.:/mnt/c/Users/me/ho/hum
```

then you could set `/mnt/c/Users/me/ho/hum/bin` as your working directory with just

```
cd bin
```

Note that if your intended destination has a common name (`bin`), the order of entries in your `CDPATH` variable will be important.  If your working directory were `/usr/local` and `CDPATH` set as per the previous paragraph, then `cd bin` would take you to `/usr/local/bin` rather than `/mnt/c/Users/me/ho/hum/bin`.