# How can I cp different files to an alias that is changing

Tags: alias, cp

I would like to be able to replace

```
cp x.x ~/some/long/directory/that/is/deeply/nested/
```

with

```
cp x.x s1
```

where s1 is an alias that points to `/some/long/directory/that/is/deeply/nested/`

However the destination frequently changes.
Today it is

```
/some/long/directory/that/is/deeply/nested/
```

next day it is

```
/some/long/directory/less/deep
```

next day it is

```
/some/other/directory/less/deep
```

Given that it is changing all the time is there an alias (or more likely function? as I think about it), is there a way I can do a cp with the destination being an 'interpreted' alias

something like

```
cp x.x `s`
```

The 'source' file was also be many different values.  I don't want an alias that just points to one (or a list of a few) location or is for 1 (or a list of a few) source file.  I want it to be whatever the alias points to at that time and the filename would be supplied when invoking it.

Source and destination could be any of thousands of values.

Comment: You need a function here, alias wouldn't help.

Comment: *How* is `s1` being changed?  Or are you asking what `s1` should be and how it should be changed?  If the latter, a symlink seems the obvious answer.

Comment: Any reason why not make a link `s` in your home directory to the 'directory-of-the-day' and just use `cp filename ~/s`? Then you can have a script creates/updates the link, you don't have to resource any alias, function or variable in all open terminals?

Comment: there are dozens of given values on a given day

Comment: @MichaelDurrant As long as at any given time things are unique you can have one or more (symbolic) links pointing to the right direction. Update the links through some script based on a cron job as often as circumstances require. The links will point to the right location, without any need to update variables or functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Shell variable

You could accomplish this by adding the directories that you want to put in `s1` in variables instead like so:

```
s1=/some/long/directory/that/is/deeply/nested/
```

You can then access these like this:

```
$ cp x.x $s1
```

#### Symbolic link

You could maintain a link in your home directory that merely points to today's long directory.

```
$ ln /some/long/directory/that/is/deeply/nested/ $HOME/shortlink
$ cp x.x $HOME/shortlink
```

#### Directory Bookmarking Tools

Take a look at this Q & A  titled: [Quick directory navigation in the terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31161/quick-directory-navigation-in-the-terminal/31345#31345). Tools such as [autojump](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump/) or [xd - eXtra fast Directory changer](http://xd-home.sourceforge.net/xdman.html), can be used as well to "bookmark" frequently used directories so that you can easily change to them without having to type long paths.

#### References

- [How to create a short path?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93022/how-to-create-a-short-path)

Comment: Disadvantages of the variable approach is IMHO that you need to remember to refresh the value when the target-directory-of-the-day changes. I.e. in every open terminal/shell.

Comment: @Anthon - very good point!

Comment: it's actually changing throughout the day.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant we can't really help unless you explain _how_ it is changing. How can your system determine what the value should be?

Comment: Sure.  Thanks tendon! :) ok, so the source file is only chosen at the time that the cp is done.  So would probably be STDIN.  The output location would be whatever the alias points to that that moment.  I want the same benefits from an alias that it provides at the command line, i.e. it's a shortcut and you can change what it is at will and the shortcut ('left side') remains the same

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
mdhf="/home/MichaelDurrant/linq
params="$@"
[[ $params = *-d* ]] && nufile=${params##*\-f}
[[ $nufile ]] && [ -L "$mdhf" ] && rm $mdhf 
[[ $nufile ]] && ln -s $nufile $mdhf 
for i in "$@"; do
[[ $i = '-d' ]] && break 
cp -v $i $mdhf
done
```

Usage would be `mdcp filename -d directory`. You'd only use the -d parameter if you were changing the current softlinked directory.