# How do I create a symbol to represent a path to easily cd into a directory?

Tags: bash, shell, directory, cd-command

In the same way that `cd ~` directs you to your home directory, is it possible to create another symbol, `@` for example, such that `cd @` would take me to `/my/working/directory`?

Comment: Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31161/quick-directory-navigation-in-the-bash-shell/31345#31345. This Q&A has a whole host of tools to help navigate directories via CLI.

Comment: Put this to your .bashrc: `[[ ! -e ~/@ ]] && ln -s /my/working/directory ~/@; CDPATH=~`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options come to mind:

- Use a variable:

  ```
  w="/my/working/directory"
  cd "$w"
  ```
- Use an alias:

  ```
  alias cdw='cd /my/working/directory'
  cdw
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CDPATH variable to simulate it. Just create a directory with soft links to the destination paths, e.g.

```
mkdir ~/dir_aliases
ln -s /path/to/alias ~/dir_aliases/@
ln -s /another/path ~/dir_aliases/%
...
```

Then add this dir to CDPATH (probably in .bashrc or similar)

```
CDPATH=~/dir_aliases
```

Typing

```
cd @
```

will take you to `~/dir_aliases/@`. (Unfortunately, the link path will be shown, you'll have to

```
cd $(readlink -f .)
```

to see the real path.)

Comment: `cd -P` is a simpler way than using `readlink` to use the real path.